# How to applied the calculus vectorial properties?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

The problem is concerning to develop the correct algebra applying the calculus properties. The question is in the figure embedded.

We have the following Helmholtz (vector-scalar)  equation given by

\begin{align}
\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\phi + \left( \nabla - i \vec{A}\right)^2 \phi=0 
\end{align}

where $\vec{A}$ is a vector and $\phi$ is scalar function.

Of course, the second term is square also this a vector operator.

The question is how to develop the right algebra for the second term ?
\begin{align*}
\left( \nabla - i \vec{A}\right) \left( \nabla - i \vec{A}\right) \phi
\end{align*}
or 
\begin{align*}
\left( \nabla - i \vec{A}\right) \cdot \left( \nabla - i \vec{A}\right) \phi
\end{align*}

We can make at first sight the analogy $(a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b)$, valid for real numbers or the vectorial case version, but here scalar and vector (funtions) are mixed.

[Question to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz2UR.png)

Comment: It should be the dot operator since you have a scalar equation (the function $\phi$ is a scalar).  Compare this to the Laplacian operator $\nabla^2$, where $\nabla^2 u = \nabla \cdot \nabla u$.

Comment: It can't be something like $\vec v\vec v=\vec v^2=v_1^2+v_2^2+\dots+v_n^2$?

Comment: @manooooh $\vec{v} \vec{v}$ has no meaning.